# FrcPath part 2 exam in the uk april 2019

Tags: visas, uk

The case here is being married so we have revenue streams but not enough to cover the trip, how they will see that a family member sponsor their married adult.

My mother who works in the KSA can support financing my trip visa app 
how can I manage the application? I live in Egypt, married and with children, travelling alone for 4 days to sit the frcpath part 2 exam. I have proof of passing part 1, paid the examination fees for part 2 and have a proof of payment and invitation letter from the royal college. My salary and my husband's salary cover the monthly household only.

Comment: What is frcpath ?

Comment: stands for Fellow of the Royal College of Pathologists

Comment: @Adout Read the answer linked to, and if that does not cover your case edit the question to ask the specific thing that is not covered.